# python pandas TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame, `df_data`, want to use the pandas index.asof() method to find the nearest row to a specified time. The times I have are in seconds (type = float64) (see below).

Originally, the index was made to be a DateTimeIndex:

```
In [12]: df_data.index = pd.to_datetime(df_data.index, coerce=True) 
         df_data.index.dtype
Out[12]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Then, I changed the index to be in seconds from the initial time:

```
In [22]: ## Convert the index from DateTimeIndex to a float64 
         ## that is the number of seconds from the initial measurement
         df_data.index = (df_data.index - df_data.index[0])/np.timedelta64(1,'s')
In [23]: df_data.index.dtype
Out[23]: dtype('float64')
```

But when I try to use the asof method with a float, I get a TypeError:

```
In [24]: df_data.index.asof(10.0)
...
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'
```

I have tried to use datetime, datetime.fromtimestamp, etc., but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Although this is not stated clearly in the docs, I think `asof` only works with a DatetimeIndex, and not with other index types.

Comment: @joris: I think you are right about the `asof` being limited to DateTimeIndex. I have edited my code to use the method (and save the results) before changing my index from DateTime to float. I have edited the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @joris for the insightful comment.

**SOLUTION**

Before changing the index from DateTimeIndex to a float (i.e., seconds from initial measurement as described in the question), you need to identify the times (in this case I use a simple example with one time `time_float`) at which you'd like to find the nearest index. Then, those datetime indices can be transformed to float indices:

```
In [21]: time_float = 10.0
         time_td = df_data.index[0]+ datetime.timedelta(0,time_float)
         ## convert from the DateTimeIndex type to time from start in seconds as type float64
         time_index = (df_data.index.asof(time_td) - df_data.index[0]).total_seconds()
         time_index
Out[21]: 9.86296
```

Now, after the overall conversion of the index (given above) to seconds from the initial time, I can refer to the index closest to `time_float`, which is `time_index`:

```
In [24]: df_data.ix[time_index,0]
Out[24]: 0.00075450129999999997
```